# Susy maths adjustment to particular layout

Tags: susy-compass

Working on a Drupal site with a Zen sub theme, I ditched zen-grids for susy. I have been playing around with Susy and it works nicely. But here is my question.

I have a layout with two main columns: **#content** (holding the main content; a grid of three rows of four images with a width of 181px)  and **div.region-sidebar-second** (holding the main navigation).

My designer came up with a 960px layout, where the #content container’s width is 750px then there is a 8px right-margin and div.region-sidebar-second has a width of 202px.

In my responsive.scss I put:

```
.sidebar-second {
#content {
@include span-columns(9, 12);
}
.region-sidebar-second {
@include span-columns(3 omega, 12);
}
}
```

So #content uses the first 9 columns and .region-sidebar-second uses the last 3 columns. But this does not translate to 750px/8px/202px.

The percentages that susy calculates are correct, of course, but for my layout I would need Susy to calculate different percentages.

E.g. Susy calculates for #content

```
.sidebar-second #content {
float: left;
margin-right: 1.40845%;
width: 74.6479%;
}
```

and for

```
.sidebar-second .region-sidebar-second {
float: right;
margin-right: 0;
width: 23.9437%;
}
```

In order to meet the design requirements I would need a width: 78.125% for #content, .833333% for margin-right and a width: 21.0416666% for .region-sidebar-second

Not sure whether this can be achieved with Susy span-columns. If you have a quick idea this would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Susy is completely customizable. Have you established the grid settings you want? You can set `$total-column`, `$column-width`, `$gutter-width`, `$grid-padding` etc. If the current ratios are wrong, just change the settings.

Comment: Sorry, maybe this is just a stupid question. In order to clarify what I have written above. My html looks like this. 
`<div id="main"><div id="content"></div><div class="region-sidebar-second"></div></div>`. 
#main is 960px; #content is 750px and a margin-right of 8px; div.region-sidebar-second is 202px. My suzy grid settings are as follows:  `$total-columns : 12;
 $column-width  : 5em;
 $gutter-width  : 1em;
 $grid-padding  : $gutter-width;`

Comment: Not sure how to change the susy grid settings because 750px and 202px don't go together, do they?

Comment: I admit the design widths are clumsy but I approximated the layout with the following ratios (and a lot of calculating): 
`$total-columns : 28;
$column-width  : 2.25em;
$gutter-width  : .5em;
$grid-padding  : 0em;`

Comment: I don't know if 202px and 750px "go together" - I haven't seen your design. :) It sounds like maybe your designer wasn't using a grid, but you want to overlay one onto the design? There's nothing magic about that - and your approximation is as good as mine. You can set up Susy with `px` instead of `em`s, if that makes your math easier.

Comment: You are completely right, Eric. The layout from the designer doesn't use a grid layout and thus makes it hard to get susy create a proper grid setup. Some experimenting with different $ctotal-columns and $column-width setups resulted in a susy grid layout that approximated the design as close as possible. In order to get the #content box to match the 750px, in my styles.scss I had to adjust the width of #content with percentages: `#content {width: 78.125%;} // 750/960`

Will have a talk with the designer and update her on grid systems. Thanks for your time and input, Eric!

Comment: Susy 2 is nearly out of alpha, and has the ability to handle arbitrary widths: `span(78%)` etc. In the meantime, I hope that works well for you!